# psad does not detect nmap

Tags: security, port, nmap, psad

I am new to this and just installed psad. I ran nmap several times on a server but psad didn't log this `psad --Status`.

I configured it like this: http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-install-psad-intrusion-detection-ubuntu-1204-lts-server

My aim is to prevent port checking attacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Psad does not prevent from being scanned, it will only help detect it. Moreover, you cannot really prevent it (unless you can set a closed whitelist of IPs), and the best you can do is react on psad messages using something like [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org) filters. An example of a such filter being:

```
[Definition]
failregex = psad: scan detected: .*
ignoreregex =
```

Define the `DANGER_LEVEL_?` thresholds in `/etc/psad/psad.conf` to something that suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks. So is it possible to detect a port check and start a script that bans the IP or other client info from accessing the server?
How could it be done?

Comment: As I outlined above, using fail2ban and adding that filter. Also review the psad.conf to define sensible thresholds.